# React Native Multiple fetch vs Filter

Tags: react-native, filter, server

I have a Screen where I am displaying products from a server and filtering the products by recent added, most rated and promotion in the same screen and I was wondering which is better fetching all products once and filtering it or calling the server three times for the specific products because the products are too many and it may takes time fetching them all once.

Comment: Had the same scenario, where i need to fetch quiz detail , questions and their respective answers. Did the filter process to fetch only particular quiz at back-end. Fetching all the useless record in your app does not sound good.

Comment: what about calling the server multiple times?